# Moment JS get difference in Timezone for countdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I'm working with Moment JS in my Nuxt JS project. I'm building a countdown timer which needs to count down to a specific date & time, ideally, I need it to display the same countdown information based on timezone in the user's country, I need it to countdown to a date & time in Europe/London though.

This is my method:

```js
/*
** Set time left
*/
setCountdown () {
  var date = this.$moment.utc(this.endDate).format()

  console.log(date)

  const end = this.$moment.utc(date).local()
  const timeLeft = this.$moment(end.diff(this.$moment()))
  const daysLeft = end.diff(this.$moment(), 'days')

  this.countdown.days = daysLeft
  this.countdown.hours = timeLeft.format('HH')
  this.countdown.minutes = timeLeft.format('mm')
  this.countdown.seconds = timeLeft.format('ss')
},
```

The date I want to countdown to is: **2022-11-09 20:00:00** and the time in my country right now is **2022-11-09 19:00:00**, despite putting `this.$moment.tz.guess()` within the `end` date, it still shows 2 hours away, where am I missing my timezone from in my code?

Comment: MomentJS is dead, try to use something else if possible.

Comment: This is a production system so cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

use UTC if you use UTC its the universal timezone. Then when a user looks at the time it will subtract for there timezone and keep a universal time while showing each time zone correctly. https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboututc.shtml

```js
moment.utc(yourDate).format()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you update your answer with a bit more of my code and what part I should replace? I tried replacing my `const end` value with `this.$moment.utc(this.endDate).format()` _(this.endDate comes as a string)_ and my error is now: "end.diff is not a function"

Comment: yes see answer below

Answer (score 0):

yes here is an example from UTC to local:

```js
var date = moment.utc().format();
console.log(date, "- now in UTC"); 

var local = moment.utc(date).local().format();
console.log(local, "- UTC now to local");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure on the implementation here. I've updated my original description with your code, but the time is still out. It's currently 15:05:00 in GMT/London time, I've set my `endDate` as a string to: `2022-11-12 16:05:00` and the end result thinks it's 2 hours away. What am I missing/